# How to add Search in Details Modal Picker lightswitch

Tags: c#, javascript, lightswitch-2013

On my screen i have Details modal picker which gives all accounts(Contracter) name from tb_account.
I want to add search in the Contracter dialog, I have already made a sorted and filtered query, and binded to "Contracter's Details modal picker" but can't figure how to add search in Contracter Dialog.

see image:

[image: need search box]

I am using Lightswitch 2013 Html Client with c# and JS.
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have updated visual studio 2013 to march update and it now provides autocomplete and searchable picker so my problem is solved.
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/lightswitch/archive/2014/03/03/office-developer-tools-for-visual-studio-2013-march-2014-update.aspx

hope it'll help someone

Comment: It did, thanks dude. It also worth to mention that the way to update the project to the latest version is Right Click on the LS project then click on "Upgrade Project"

Answer (score 2):

First, create a new Edit Screen, e.g. PickJobScreen, with a List/Table control bound to a 'Job' query - if you are using Lightswitch 2013 and the 'Job' entities are searchable ("IsSearchable" = true), you'll get the filtering capability more or less out of the box, otherwise just display a TextBox control above the List/Table control, bind this Textbox to a new, e.g. 'SearchText', screen propery and correlate it with the filter of the query.

Then, on the Daily 'Expense Screen', add a Button or similar to open the above screen, wiring everything up like:

```
myapp.ExpenseScreen.PickJob_execute = function (screen) {
  myapp.showPickJobScreen({
    null,
    afterClosed: function (pickJobScreen, navigationAction) {
        if (navigationAction === msls.NavigateBackAction.commit) {
            var selectedJob = pickJobScreen.Jobs.selectedItem;
            screen.Job = selectedJob;
        }
    }
  })
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Please read out this from this link, 
    there mention all step with screenshot with standard code:
    Please, [click here][1]

```
  [1]: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/bethmassi/archive/2013/11/04/beginning-lightswitch-in-vs-2013-part-3-screen-templates-which-one-do-i-choose.aspx
```

Comment: this is not what i want, i want to add search in the details modal picker, can you provide link related to that